# Defining a program local pointer of a structure

Tags: c, pointers, scope, structure

my question deals with creating variables that are visible throughout the program file.  In other words, a *file-local* variable.

Consider this example

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct foo
{
    char s[] = "HELLO";
    int n = 5;
};

struct foo *a;

int main()
{
    puts("Dummy outputs!\n");
    printf("%s\n",a->s);
    printf("%d\n",a->n);
    return 0;
}
```

Now, this code snippet won't **run**.
Why?
Because the structure pointed to be pointer variable *a* will not get **allocated** as the statement never executed.

Now, how do you get it allocated without changing the scope of this  variable *a*?

Comment: It won't run becasue you have not initialised `a`. It doesn't point to anything.

Comment: the same way you allocate any other pointer...

Comment: change **char[] s;** to **char s[SomeSize]";**

Comment: You do not need the `\0` for a start

Comment: It remains the same until you change it.

Comment: There are no member functions in C. Are you sure you are learning the right language?

Comment: so, how would you allocate the structure (say) inside main? @WeatherVane

Comment: I agree.. I seem to have used the wrong term.. :P @n.m.

Comment: I think you need [This](http://ideone.com/FRwODG)

Comment: @Adil the answer from Loic beat me to it. It declares the struct, before defining an instance of it, which is initialised. He doesn't use a pointer. Don't you a pointer if you don't have to.

Comment: no, that would make a visible only in one function.. I need it to remain visible throughout the program

Comment: There is no need for pointers for such a task. [Try This](http://ideone.com/ERCh4I)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct foo {
    char const *s;
    int n;
};

/* static for file-local */
static struct foo a = { "HELLO" , 5 };

int main(void) {
    printf("%s\n", a.s);
    printf("%d\n", a.n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: well, i need to use a **pointer** instead of a **structure** directly

Comment: @Adil Why? Can't you just use &a?

Answer (score 1):

> Now, how do you get it allocated without changing the scope of this variable a?

I am sure there a lot of ways to solve your problem. Here's my suggestion.

1. Change the definition of `struct foo` to contain a fixed number of characters in `s`.
2. Create `a` as an object instead of a pointer. Initialize it with the necessary values.
3. Make `a` a `static` variable so its use is limited to the file only.
4. Use the object `a` instead of the pointer `a` in rest of the file.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct foo
{
   char s[20];
   int n;
};

static struct foo a = {"HELLO", 20};

int main()
{
    puts("Dummy outputs!\n");
    printf("%s\n",a.s);
    printf("%d\n",a.n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the data inside the structure is not static.. it will be changed through the program.. How would you do it if the char s[] is replaced by a double dimensional array?

Comment: @Adil now you are asking a new question. You clearly show a one-dimensional array.

Comment: @Adil, that's a separate question than what your post talks about. If the answers to your post resolve your doubts about the questions mentioned in the post, accept one of the answers. Then ask other questions in a different post.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
struct foo
{
    char s[] = "HELLO";
    int n = 5;
};
```

Is not valid C code.  You first declare the type:

```
struct foo
{
    char s[10];
    int n;
};
```

Then define a variable of that type:

```
static struct foo a = { "HELLO", 5 };
```

The `static` keyword allows this variable to have file local scope.

You can now use it like this:

```
static struct foo a = { "HELLO", 5 };

void other()
{
    puts("Dummy outputs!\n");
    printf("%s\n",a.s);
    printf("%d\n",a.n);
}

int main()
{
    puts("Dummy outputs!\n");
    printf("%s\n",a.s);
    printf("%d\n",a.n);
    other();
    return 0;
}
```

Note that `a` is accessible from both functions.  It will not however be viewable from functions defined in other files because it is declared as `static`.

As for using a pointer vs the struct directly, you can take the address of this structure at any time you need to use it in that way:

```
some_function(&a);
```

Answer (score 0):

> well, i need to use a pointer instead of a structure directly

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct foo{
    char s[20];
    int n;
};


int main(void){
    struct foo *a;
    a = malloc(sizeof(struct foo));
    puts("Dummy outputs!\n");
    strcpy(a->s, "HELLO");
    a->n = 5;
    printf("%s\n",a->s);
    printf("%d\n",a->n);

    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> ```
> Dummy outputs!
> HELLO
> 5
> ```